# How proper HIHI sounds like?

Tags: cw, jargon

Recently I've read [Zen And The Art Of Radiotelegraphy](https://www.qsl.net/ik0ygj/enu/index.html) by Carlo Consoli, IK0YGJ. I must say, it's a great book, and as a new CW operator I've found plenty of useful information in it.

What especially catched my attention was:

> This  freedom  of  manipulating  a  telegraph  key  produces  very 
>   interesting phenomena: the laughter, HI, for example, is not
>   transmitted accurately H (four dots), followed with the proper spacing
>   by the I (two dots), it but is transmitted as four-dots, a  light 
>   syncope,  a  dot,  another  syncope  and  a  final  dot.  The 
>   resulting  sound  is incredibly similar to that of a real laugh.  Once
>   heard, it cannot be forgot.

Sadly I couldn't find a recording of a proper HIHI sound, nor I encountered it on the air. Maybe someone knows a video on YouTube that demonstrates how HIHI supposed to sound? Or, if it's not too much trouble, could you please record this sound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People sending `HI` tend to fall into two camps. Some people send a correct `HI`, as if they learned that `HI` means laughter, and they want to send that accurately at all times. The second camp learned by listening, and they tend to send something that sounds more like `HEE`. This latter version is the one being described in the text you quoted.

The `HEE` version sounds more ‘playful’ than the `HI` version, to my ears, and I think that was the original intention.

You can find examples of this by listening to the bands - especially the lower bands such as 80m, where you can usually still find a good rag chew on CW between old-timers.

Comment: Electronic keyers sure have flattened a lot of the character out of Morse code...  (Full disclosure: I use a keyer most of the time, although I do have two straight keys.)

Comment: Agreed. I always use an electronic keyer these days, but recently tried a straight key for the first time in years. It was actually fun! But it did tire my wrist quite quickly. I clearly need to practise more :)